# Multiple Join to return only matching fields

Tags: sql, join

Need to run multiple joins where only matching rows will be returned.
I would like to get values only from matching rows

I have such query:

```
select dc.STATUSWORK "DC STATUS", de.STATUSWORK "DE STATUS", r.STATUSWORK "R STATUS", g.STATUSWORK "G STATUS", c.STATUSWORK "CONTRACT Status", c.PYID 
from CONTRACT c
join VDC dc on (dc.COVERKEY = c.KEY)
join VDE de on (de.COVERKEY = c.KEY)
join RCK r on (r.COVERKEY = c.KEY)
join GDE g on (g.COVERKEY = c.KEY)
join CDOC c on (c.COVERKEY = c.KEY)
where c.PYID = 'C-1000';
```

For sure if not all the join conditions together are matching, no rows will be returned, if I use some left or right join, also rows with NULL values will be returned

How can I  run the query to check before what are the matching rows and feed a new query to return only the matching tables/rows?

Comment: Simplify your question. (Max 3 tables should be needed here to illustrate the problem.) Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.) Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex.

Comment: `JOIN` does what you want.

Comment: Hi @Morgan Forever, as jarlh has said, we need an idea of what your data tables look like and what result you are trying to achieve. E.g. it's not clear if you want ALL data from ALL tables, or maybe ALL the CONTRACT data and data from the other tables only if they keys match or something else entirely.

Comment: Hi Duggie, I recognize I was too short of details cause I'm working right now and could not make a proper example but yes, the second case you mentioned is exactly what I want: I would need All the CONTRACT data and data from the other tables only if they keys match

Comment: There are 2 ways I can think of. If you did all ALL Left Joins based on CONTRACT as the initial table, you would get ALL the records in Contract plus any that match CONTRACT in the other tables. The other way is to do several queries and UNION the results. Try them both and use whichever gives the output you are looking for.

Comment: Part of a [mcve] is a clear specification--a description of how the result you want is a function of the input. But you do not give one. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When describing a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. You don't. You don't even give an example so we can't even guess what that is. Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, this should do it.  This will return all rows from Contract as long as they have a match in at least one of the other rows.  Switch out the ORs for ANDs if you need all tables to have a match.

```
select dc.STATUSWORK "DC STATUS"
   , de.STATUSWORK "DE STATUS"
   , r.STATUSWORK "R STATUS"
   , g.STATUSWORK "G STATUS"
   , c.STATUSWORK "CONTRACT Status", c.PYID 
from CONTRACT c
   left join VDC dc on (dc.COVERKEY = c.KEY)
   left join VDE de on (de.COVERKEY = c.KEY)
   left join RCK r on (r.COVERKEY = c.KEY)
   left join GDE g on (g.COVERKEY = c.KEY)
   left join CDOC c on (c.COVERKEY = c.KEY)
where c.PYID = 'C-1000'
and (
       exists (Select 1 from VDE where COVERKEY = c.KEY)
       or
       exists (Select 1 from VDC where COVERKEY = c.KEY)
       or
       exists (Select 1 from RCK where COVERKEY = c.KEY)
       or
       exists (Select 1 from GDE where COVERKEY = c.KEY)
       or
       exists (Select 1 from CDOC where COVERKEY = c.KEY)
);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed, I was looking for the "exists" clause to help me out at the end :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've mocked up a few tables and a query to see if this is what you need.

```
create table CONTRACT(ConKey int, ConName varchar(20));

insert into CONTRACT(ConKey, ConName) Values(1, 'AAA');
insert into CONTRACT(ConKey, ConName) Values(2, 'BBB');
insert into CONTRACT(ConKey, ConName) Values(3, 'CCC');

create table VDC(VDCKey int, StatusWork varchar(20));  

insert into VDC(VDCKey, StatusWork) Values(1, 'Status 1');
insert into VDC(VDCKey, StatusWork) Values(3, 'Status 2');
insert into VDC(VDCKey, StatusWork) Values(4, 'Status 3');  

create table VDE(VDEKey int, StatusWork varchar(20));  

insert into VDE(VDEKey, StatusWork) Values(1, 'Status 4');
insert into VDE(VDEKey, StatusWork) Values(3, 'Status 5');
insert into VDE(VDEKey, StatusWork) Values(4, 'Status 6');  

create table RCK(RCKKey int, StatusWork varchar(20));  

insert into RCK(RCKKey, StatusWork) Values(5, 'Status 7');
insert into RCK(RCKKey, StatusWork) Values(2, 'Status 8');
insert into RCK(RCKKey, StatusWork) Values(1, 'Status 9');
```

Here is the query :-

```
Select c.ConKey, c.ConName, dc.StatusWork, de.StatusWork, r.StatusWork 
from CONTRACT c
LEFT JOIN VDC dc ON dc.VDCKey = c.ConKey
LEFT JOIN VDE de on de.VDEKey = c.ConKey
LEFT JOIN RCK r on r.RCKKey = c.ConKey;
```

This is the result :-

```
ConKey  ConName StatusWork  StatusWork  StatusWork
1       AAA     Status 1    Status 4    Status 9
2       BBB                             Status 8
3       CCC     Status 2    Status 5
```

Comment: Hi Duggie, thanks for your effort and help but left join is what I wanted to avoid. Many Thks anyway